# How to use Django to populate an HTML selection dropdown with data?

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to create a dropdown selection on an HTML page containing options from my database, but it keeps coming up empty without any errors or any indication as to what is wrong. I'm trying to use a trimmed down version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6063081/12352379) solution. Below is what I have:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView # Import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pathfinder.models import characterTable

[...]
class battleSimView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "battleSim.html"

    def post(request):
       item  = characterTable.objects.all() # use filter() when you have sth to filter ;)

       return render_to_response ('battleSim.html', {'items':item}, context_instance =  RequestContext(request),)
[...]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class characterTable(models.Model):
    userID = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    playerName = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    race = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    playerClass = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    strength = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    dexterity = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    constitution = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    intelligence = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    wisdom = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    charisma = models.CharField(max_length = 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.userID + ": " + self.playerName )
[...]
```

form area of battleSim.html, in my templates folder

```html
[...]
    <form method="POST">
      <select name="item_id">
      {% for entry in items %}
          <option value="{{ entry.userID }}">{{ entry.playerName }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </form>
[...]
```

I'm just not sure where down the line the issue is, or what I could do to solve it

Comment: Looks like your `battleSimView` works only on POST and you do not render variables into the template. You need to render values into form with `GET` request and after that send them via `POST`.

Comment: Hmm, how should I go about rendering values into the dropdown? The examples I've seen haven't used GET requests, but they also haven't worked for me. What should I try or look up to GET started?

Comment: How example shows, there is a check for `POST` request and after that additional work. But in any case, `items` will be passed to the render function.

Comment: Why not use Django forms (ModelForm)?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/
This would make your Django app cleaner and more maintainable.
And if you wish to customize the appearance of those forms I would suggest using https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms

Comment: @gagamil, this is my first time using Django, so I apologize for how much of a novice I am. I've seen many suggestions in a lot of examples I've seen recommending forms through Django. They seem straightforward enough, but if this is the only form I will be submitting on my entire project, is it worth having an extra moving part, or would it make my life easier if I forego the HTML form route?

Comment: @nunzio I would recommend you going the Django way.
There are couple of reasons for this:
1st since you're using that framework try to do it the Django way aka best practices
2nd leverage what the framework offers you. Makes little sense to use it if you're doing every small step manually
3rd learn the framework. It will make you better as developer and more efficient. Every software has a cost of maintenance. So automate and offsource anything you can. Less code written less bugs.

Comment: @nunzio I would also use specialized Class Based views to handle forms. Not TemplateView based class. ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms ).
And class names better be Capitalized.