# filter select field in django using ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I have a form with two fields related to each other and I want the rooms filtered based on the class in the front form.

This is my code:

models.py

```py
class Class(models.Model):

    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name

class Room(models.Model):

    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class,related_name='class',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room_name
```

views.py

```py
class CustomFormView(LoginMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'form.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['class'] = Class.objects.values('pk','class_name')
        context['rooms'] = Room.objects.all()
        return self.render_to_response(context)

def get_related_rooms(request):
    class_id = request.GET.get('class_id')
    rooms = Room.objects.filter(class_id=class_id)
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'rooms': rooms})
```

form.html

```html
      <form id="custom_form" data-rooms-url="{% url 'app:get_related_rooms' %}">
     Class Name:
        <select type="text" class="form-control"id="class_name" onchange="test()" name="class_name">
           {% for c in class %}
               <option value="{{ c.pk }}">{{ c.class_name }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
         </select>
      Room Name:
          </label>
            <select type="text" class="form-control" id="room_name" name="room_name">
          </select>
</form>
//here is the ajax call to get the rooms 
<script>
  function test() {
    var classId = document.getElementById("class_name").value; 
    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'calculator:get_related_rooms' %}" ,
      method: 'GET',
      data: {
          'class_id': classId
      },
      success: function (result) {
        // console.log(result)
          $("#room_name").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", 'pk').text('room_name'));
      }
    })
  };
  </script>
```

The option `.text('room_name'));` is inserted when I select from class drop down , but I want it to come from the database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Dropdown populate from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062742/django-dropdown-populate-from-database)

Comment: no the isuue I'm facing is that I have the queryset with correct result comming but I dont know how to get it from ajax code and put it in <option>