# Django views and HTML form

Tags: python, django

I have created a form in HTML and I want to bind it to a model, but I do not know how to make it possible to select a form from the database data by the type of a drop-down list. (For example, the name of the doctor and patient that should already be stored in the database.)

When I do this through creating a form through django, everything works out, but I'm interested in HTML.

I get this error :

> ValueError at /create_appointment/ Cannot assign "'patient'":
> "Appointment.patient" must be a "Patient" instance.

models.py

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    time_appointment = models.DateTimeField()
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient, related_name='patient_to_appointment', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(
        Doctor, related_name='doctor_appointment', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    complaint = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
   def create_appointment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        datetime = request.POST['datetime']
        patient = request.POST['patient']
        doctor = request.POST['doctor']
        service = request.POST['service']

        appointform = Appointment(
            time_appointment=datetime, patient=patient, doctor=doctor, complaint=service)
        appointform.save()
        return redirect('/appointment')
    return render(request, 'main/f_appointment.html')
```

html

```
<body>
  <div class="text-center mt-5">
    <form style="max-width: 480px; margin: auto" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <p class="hint-text mb-3">Please sign in</p>
      <label class="sr-only" for="datetime"></label>
      <input
        type="datetime-local"
        name="datetime"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="гггг-мм-дд чч:мм:сс время и дата записи"
        required
        autofocus
      />
      <label for="patient" class="sr-only"></label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="patient"
        class="form-control mt-2"
        placeholder="пациент"
      />
      <label for="doctor" class="sr-only"></label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="doctor"
        class="form-control mt-2"
        placeholder="доктор"
      />
      <label for="service" class="sr-only"></label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="service"
        class="form-control mt-2"
        placeholder="услуга"
      />

      <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-4">
        <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="sign in" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</body>
```

Comment: Your solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062742/django-dropdown-populate-from-database  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130706/dropdown-in-django-model

Answer (score 0):

Django does alot of this for you if you use [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/). This will traverse relationships and provide much of the functionality you need.

Comment: can't figure out how to customize the style using django widgets

Comment: you can add class attributes that then can be styled with SASS/CSS. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances

django-crispy-forms does some extensible built-in styling with Bootstrap, if you are into that kind of thing.